# Android/Java ArrayList Error

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Im using a library to read contacts on Android SDK and ive been trying to adapt the solution for a successful build and proper function. The issue I am running into is that the ArrayList is not being recognized which I'm guessing is a symptom of a small issue (perhaps breakpoints) or related to layout issues. I'm still fairly new with Android so thank you for your help.

The mainactivity.java code is below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contactlist_android_items);
    }

    public class Android_Contact {
        public String android_contact_Name = "";
        public String android_contact_TelefonNr = "";
        public int android_contact_ID = 0;

        public void fp_get_Android_Contacts() {
            ArrayList<Android_Contact> arrayList_Android_Contacts = new ArrayList<Android_Contact>();
        }

        Cursor cursor_Android_Contacts = null;
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        try {
            cursor_Android_Contacts = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        } catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e("Error on contact", ex.getMessage());
        }
        if(cursor_Android_Contacts.getCount()>0) {
            while (cursor_Android_Contacts.moveToNext()) {
                Android_Contact android_contact = new Android_Contact();
                String contact_id = cursor_Android_Contacts.getString(cursor_Android_Contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String contact_display_name = cursor_Android_Contacts.getString(cursor_Android_Contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                android_contact.android_contact_Name = contact_display_name;
                int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor_Android_Contacts.getString(cursor_Android_Contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
                if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                    Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI
                            , null
                            , ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?"
                            , new String[]{contact_id}
                            , null);
                    while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                        android_contact.android_contact_TelefonNr = phoneNumber;
                    }
                    phoneCursor.close();
                }
                arrayList_Android_Contacts.add(android_contact);
            }

            Adapter_for_Android_Contacts adapter = new Adapter_for_Android_Contacts(this, arrayList_Android_Contacts);
            listView_Android_Contacts.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    public class Adapter_for_Android_Contacts extends BaseAdapter {
        Context mContext;
        List<Android_Contact> mList_Android_Contacts;

        public Adapter_for_Android_Contacts(Context mContext, List<Android_Contact> mContact) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.mList_Android_Contacts = mContact;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mList_Android_Contacts.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mList_Android_Contacts.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.contactlist_android_items, null);
            TextView textview_contact_Name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_android_contact_name);
            TextView textview_contact_TelefonNr = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_android_contact_phoneNr);
           textview_contact_Name
             .setText(mList_Android_Contacts
                       .get(position).android_contact_Name);
            textview_contact_TelefonNr
              .setText(mList_Android_Contacts
                        .get(position).android_contact_TelefonNr);
     view.setTag(mList_Android_Contacts
                   .get(position).android_contact_Name);
            return view;
        }
    }
    }
while (cursor_Android_Contacts.moveToNext()) {
                Android_Contact android_contact = new Android_Contact();
                String contact_id = cursor_Android_Contacts.getString(cursor_Android_Contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String contact_display_name = cursor_Android_Contacts.getString(cursor_Android_Contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                android_contact.android_contact_Name = contact_display_name;


//----< get phone number >----
                int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor_Android_Contacts.getString(cursor_Android_Contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
                if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {

                    Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI
                            , null
                            , ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?"
                            , new String[]{contact_id}
                            , null);

                    while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
//< set >
                        android_contact.android_contact_TelefonNr = phoneNumber;
//</ set >
                    }
                    phoneCursor.close();
                }
//----</ set >----
//----</ get phone number >----

// Add the contact to the ArrayList
                arrayList_Android_Contacts.add(android_contact);
            }
//----</ @Loop: all Contacts >----
//< show results >
            Adapter_for_Android_Contacts adapter = new Adapter_for_Android_Contacts(this, arrayList_Android_Contacts);
            listView_Android_Contacts.setAdapter(adapter);
//</ show results >
```

Comment: please add stacktrace to show the errors you're getting

Comment: You got an error, but didn't even tell us what it is?

Comment: what's the exception you're getting? stacktrace is needed pls

Comment: As I was describing the error messages do not give insight into the root of the problem. They are either ';' expected or illegal start type. The issue is that basic keywords such as TextView, BaseAdapter, View, arrayList_Android_Contacts, listView_Android_Contacts and ArrayList are being marked as unidentifiable, 'cannot resolve symbol' is the message. I suspect this is either a layout connection issue or class/namespacing issue.

Comment: when I hover over the ArrayList keyword sometimes a message appears above saying 'java.util.Arraylist?' I assume it is not loading this package. Does anyone run into such issues too?

Comment: Have added the proper import to your packages (namespaces?)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your arrayList_Android_Contacts is not declared in all the scopes you are using it. Putting it as a member of your class will probably do the trick (from a compilation perspective):

```
   public class Android_Contact {
        public String android_contact_Name = "";
        public String android_contact_TelefonNr = "";
        public int android_contact_ID = 0;
        private ArrayList<Android_Contact> arrayList_Android_Contacts = new ArrayList<Android_Contact>();
   ....
   }
```

Another thing you should probably do is to remove or change `fp_get_Android_Contacts()`.